# Difference between "On your mark, get set, go" and "Ready, steady, go"

Tags: phrases, differences

Watching *Kipper* with my son tonight, I was struck by the phrase "Ready, steady, go!"  I don't often hear this sequence.  In my upbringing, it has been mostly "On your mark, get set, go!"

I had thought the difference might be between British English and North American English, but when I search for "Ready Steady Go," I get a whole lot of unrelated hits related to music.

Is there a regional preference in the usage of these phrases to start a race, or are they perhaps associated with particular sports?

Comment: There is also "ready, set, go."

Comment: Also, it appears [on your marks](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/on+your+mark#mark_2) is sometimes plural, which sounds funny to me even though it makes sense (I think I usually have heard "on your mark" no matter how many runners).

Comment: Are we talking about races where the starter is a professional with a rule book in his/her hand, or an informal race where the starter simply tries to recall what he/she has heard others use?

Comment: @pavium I'd say informal.  The "professional" races I've been in usually start with "Runners, take your marks."

Comment: I've heard *on your mark* often enough, but the singular always strikes me as a bit odd. The phrase invariably applies to *multiple* contestants; I assume each of them has their own mark, and the starter is addressing them collectively. So only *marks* really makes sense to me.

Comment: i would daresay British English. cos i live in India ( India was a British colony ) and when i was ten i heard "on your marks..." on our sports field. i was so very confused. marks? as in exam?  i had to wait for my uncle (he was my encyclopedia. plus there was no Google ) for three months to get an explanation. thank god for Google and SO.they do have information , not just plain data. :) BTW, our school has got no "marks" at all. just a bunch of runners leaning forward to run :)

Comment: Public school/outdated, or it's just 4-3-2-1 instead of 3-2-1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oxford learner's dictionary does indicate that there is a dialect difference for
[ready, steady, go](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/ready) (see *idioms*):

> *ready, steady, go!* (BRITISH ENGLISH) *(also (get) ready, (get) set, go* NORTH AMERICAN ENGLISH, BRITISH ENGLISH) what you say to tell people to start a race

Comment: That is what reported also from the OED.

Comment: +1. The first time I heard "Ready, steady, go" (I think from a TV show title) I was really confused until I figured out that was just how Brits say "Ready, set, go".

Answer (score 11):

I've always understood *ready, steady (or set) go* to be a more generic form of *on your mark, get set, go*, and I'd be inclined to use it in more relaxed situations perhaps. The latter feels more specifically like a race.

In athletics (back in school, in Australia) they used to drill us on the start of a foot race that on *on your mark*, you'd put your [toe on the line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe_the_line), on *get set*, you'd crouch down (and stick your bum in the air), then *go*.

Answer (score 1):

I've always associated *Ready, steady...* primarily with [younger] children.

*On your marks...* (and more 'formally,professionally', *Take your marks...*) seem to me far more appropriate for older competitors.

Answer (score 0):

The terms are all derived from the start of a foot race:

"On your mark"/"Take your mark"/"Ready" - Get in your lanes, put your toes (or hands if using a starting block) on the line, and prepare to run/swim/skate/bike your butt off.

"Get set"/"Set"/"Steady" - Assume and hold your "launch" pose; this is different than simply "taking your mark", because in most races with this or a similar procedure, no movement is allowed by the runners between when this is said and when the gun goes off or "go" is called. In British colloquy, the term "wait for it" is a reference to a slight movement noticed by the starter but not severe enough to call a "false start"; it's less common in American parlance.

"GO"/(starter pistol fires) - haul your carcass.